# No able to send raw json in retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have been trying to send raw json using retrofit 2 but not working, i have tried JsonObject , map but it's not working at all. I don't understand what the problem is. Works fine on Postman.
I am trying to send this request:

```
{
"incomes":[{"amount":"5566","incomeId":"345"}] 
}
```

my android code is:

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
@POST("/api/v1/addIncome")
Call<ResponseBody> addIncome(@Body Map<String, String> params);


Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        Call<ResponseBody> req = null;
        Income[] incomes = new Income[1];
        incomes[0] = income;
        params.put(URLParam.INCOMES, new Gson().toJson(incomes));
        req = CustomUtil.getCuumiAPIObject(this, URLConstant.BASE_URL).addIncome(params);
```

I know added the relavent part, rest works fine with other services, problem is of parameter.In response server gives a null value exception meaning, the parameter their is not picking up the value. Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>While sending String Map, You need to send it with `@FieldMap` instead of String Map as `@Body`.</s>

Use `@FiledMap` as below in your code:

```
@FieldMap Map<String, String> params
```

**Edit**

If you want to send your json with `@Body`, you need to send with pojo class as `@Body` by setting your value in pojo class.

Pojo class:

```
   public class Incomes {

@SerializedName("incomes")
@Expose
private List<Income> incomes = null;

public List<Income> getIncomes() {
return incomes;
}

public void setIncomes(List<Income> incomes) {
this.incomes = incomes;
}


public class Income {

@SerializedName("amount")
@Expose
private String amount;
@SerializedName("incomeId")
@Expose
private String incomeId;

public String getAmount() {
return amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
this.amount = amount;
}

public String getIncomeId() {
return incomeId;
}

public void setIncomeId(String incomeId) {
this.incomeId = incomeId;
}

}
}
```

Then you need to create object of `Incomes` class and need to set every `income` in created object of `Incomes` class.

```
Incomes incomes=new Incomes();
Incomes.Income mIncome=new Incomes().new Income();
mIncome=income;
incomes.setIncomes(mIncome);
```

Then send `Incomes` class object as `@Body` in you API request.

```
req = CustomUtil.getCuumiAPIObject(this, URLConstant.BASE_URL).addIncome(incomes);
```

You also need to change your `addIncome` method as below:

```
Call<ResponseBody> addIncome(@Body Incomes incomes);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i tried this, got an error so had to set @FormUrlEncoded
and as a result got error code 500 because like said i need to send raw json request

Comment: What you are getting in `incomes` ?

Comment: meaning?
i posted the request i need to send, it's exactly how it is

Comment: Sorry for wrong understading. Please check my updated answer.